# How to add pixels offset based on resolution

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Currently I'm displaying popups on my map using this [utility by Matt Walker](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-popup).

My code is something like this:

```
map.defaultPopup = new ol.Overlay.Popup({ panMapIfOutOfView: false });
map.addOverlay(map.defaultPopup);

// ...

var select = new ol.interaction.Select(options));          

select.getFeatures().on('change:length', function (e) {
    this.map.defaultPopup.hide();

    if (e.target.getArray().length > 0) {
        var feature = e.target.item(0);
        var center = feature.getCenter(); // getCenter is defined elsewhere
        //center[1 /* Y */] += ????;
        map.defaultPopup.show(center, "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>");
    }
});

map.addInteraction(select);
```

I can add an offset "????" and it works, but it is not resolution independent (the popup gets too far away from the feature on higher zoom levels).

I want to add a value that moves the location of the popup by the desired amount of pixels, regardless of the resolution. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm just beginning with ol3 and javascript in general, but maybe elsewhere you could define a function that will take the current zoom level number and use some clever coefficient to spit out an offset to pass to your `center[1 /* Y */] += ????` statement.

Comment: I was hopping for a more straightforward way. Trying to avoid that is the main reason behind the question (and the bounty itself).